# trouble with dynamic async iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to use the [Dynamic Async iFrame](http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance#dynamic) method, but my code isn't working and I'm confused about what I'm doing wrong.  The iFrame itself is loading, but it isn't showing the expected web page. See [what I mean](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cf1p2vab3).

Here is my code.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
    (function(d){
        var iframe = d.body.appendChild(d.createElement('iframe')),
            doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

        // style the iframe with some CSS
        iframe.style.cssText = "width:900px;height:600px;";

        doc.open().write('<body onload="' + 
            'var d = document;d.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].' + 
            'appendChild(d.createElement(\'script\')).src' + 
            '=\'http://www.uab.edu/dining/locations\'">');

        doc.close(); //iframe onload event happens

    })(document);
</script>
```

EDIT: Solution Code

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
        $(window).load( function(){
            window.map = '<%= j @college.map.html_safe %>';
            window.street_view = '<%= j @college.street_view.html_safe %>';
            window.food = '<%= j @college.food.html_safe %>';
            window.housing = '<%= j @college.housing.html_safe %>';
            window.weather = '<%= j @college.weather.html_safe %>';
            $('#map').html(map);
            $('#street_view').html(street_view);
            $('#food_iframe').html(food);
            $('#housing_iframe').html(housing);
            $('#weather_section').html(weather);
        });
    <% end %>
```

Comment: what are trying to load? "http://www.uab.edu/dining/locations" is not a javascript file

Comment: seems like it's a premature and unstable technique, i try this code in Google Chrome 29 and nothing happens

Comment: err.. I can't get a peep out of it in any browsers and his example on his site doesn't work, lmao. Have you considered fancybox.

Comment: @MichaelB. I'm trying to load this web page: http://www.uab.edu/dining/locations/.

Comment: @Chris is fancyBox just for images, or could it be for iFrames too?

Comment: @AdamZerner then you should not use script tag for it.

Comment: @AdamZerner I guess you need to rephrase the question and tell us what you are trying to do.. possibly there are alternatives

Comment: @MichaelB. I'm trying to load that web page in an iFrame.  I've got it working (using just a normal iFrame), but the loading of the iFrame slows down the site.  The technique on the site I linked to supposedly improves the loading of iFrames by making them the last thing to load.  Basically, I'm trying to improve the usability of my site by either making the iFrame load faster, or have it be the last thing to load so it doesn't interrupt the rest of the stuff that loads on the site (which is what the the site I linked to was trying to do).

Comment: Fancybox works great with iFrames there's an example half way down the page at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this jquery to load iframe when Dom is ready

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   $('#placeholder').html('<iframe src=""></iframe>');
})
```

*assuming you have some place holder with ID=placeholder..*

or when all is loaded (including images)

```
$(window).load( function(){
   $('#placeholder').html('<iframe src=""></iframe>');
})
```

Comment: Thanks!  I used your second bit of code, and it does what I wanted it to do.  I posted the code I used to anyone who's interested as an edit to the question.